# R - Performing multiple arithmetic calculations on all possible combinations in a data table

Tags: r, data.table, combinations

I am analyzing the effects of multiple fertilizers on crop yield at multiple locations. My dataset looks like this:

```
library(data.table)

# create some fake data
dat <- expand.grid(year=2017:2020,
                   field=c("field1","field2","field3"),
                   fert_name=c("fertA","fertB","fertC","fertD","fertE"),
                   stringsAsFactors=F)
dat <- data.table(dat)
set.seed(123); yld <- runif(60, min=5, max=15)
dat$yield <- yld
head(dat)
   year  field fert_name     yield
1: 2017 field1     fertA  7.875775
2: 2018 field1     fertA 12.883051
3: 2019 field1     fertA  9.089769
4: 2020 field1     fertA 13.830174
5: 2017 field2     fertA 14.404673
6: 2018 field2     fertA  5.455565
...
```

For each year, I need to compare all fertilizer combinations across fields. For example, fertA~fertB on all fields for the first year (2017). Then the same for fertA~fertC; fertA~fertD and fertA~fertE on the same year. Then so on for the next year.

My first step was to create a data table containing all possible combinations of fertilizers (excluding comparisons with themselves):

```
(dat.m <- merge(dat, dat, by=c("year","field"), allow.cartesian=T)[fert_name.x != fert_name.y])
year  field fert_name.x   yield.x fert_name.y   yield.y
1: 2017 field1       fertA  7.875775       fertB 11.775706
2: 2017 field1       fertA  7.875775       fertC 11.557058
3: 2017 field1       fertA  7.875775       fertD 12.584595
4: 2017 field1       fertA  7.875775       fertE  7.659726
5: 2017 field1       fertB 11.775706       fertA  7.875775
6: 2017 field1       fertB 11.775706       fertC 11.557058
```

Considering the `data.m` table above, I would like to create a new table with columns that will be based on the following calculations:

```
n = .N, # count of rows,
vari = var(yield.x - yield.y), # variance of yields
pvalue = t.test(yield.x - yield.y, conf.level = 0.90)$p.value, # t test of yield observations
mean.x = mean(yield.x), # average yield of the reference fertilizer
mean.y = mean(yield.y), # average yield of the comparison fertilzers
diffmean = mean(yield.x - yield.y) # average yield difference
```

The first few lines of the resulting table would (comparisons fertA~fertB and fertA~fertC in 2017) look like this:

```
year fert_name.x fert_name.y n     vari    pvalue  mean.x   mean.y   diffmean
1: 2017       fertA       fertB 3 37.40966 0.9685527 10.9316 11.04399 -0.1123929
2: 2017       fertA       fertC 3 28.61064 0.8456536 10.9316 10.4519 0.4796967
```

My real table has over 10 million rows, so ideally the solution would be `data.table`-based (i.e. fast) and with a relatively low memory footprint.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: I'd suggest moving this question to stats.stackexchange and getting advice there on using a linear model or ANOVA instead of a bunch of t-tests.

Comment: @GregorThomas I think the question is more related to how to implement the described analysis than to whether the analysis is appropriate or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with `data.table`, but this could help as a starting point.

You could try creating a vector of the operations you want to carry out as strings, then map them over the data. For the mean differences example, to get the difference expressions it would be:

```r
fert_name <- c("fertA","fertB","fertC","fertD","fertE")
operations <- all_comp <- outer(
                         fert_name, 
                         fert_name, 
                         FUN = function(x,y){paste(x,y, sep = "-")}
                       )
unique_operations = operations[upper_tri(operations, diag = F)]
```

Then with `dat` in wide form and `purrr::map()` you can do

```r
dat |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = fert_name, values_from = yield) -> dat_wide

map_dfr(unique_operations, ~dat_wide |> 
                            mutate(operation = .x,
                                    diff = eval(parse(text = .x)))
```

That should return 1 dataframe for every unique comparison of fertilizers.